# What is the best way to maintain different versions of APIs in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator and both should be running

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a use case where I need to maintain different versions of APIs inside WSO2 EI and both versions of APIs should be up and running.

Do we need to create two different APIs? or can we handle this with two different context paths?

Can you please suggest a best way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per the WSO2 document,

> At present, the ESB identifies each API by its unique context name. If
>   you introduce a version in the API context (e.g., /Service/1.0.0), you
>   can update it when you upgrade the same API (e.g., /Service/1.0.1).

So, you might have to create a new context path to keep both the API versions accessible.